# What does "maximal number of closed cutting curves that do not disconnect the graph into multiple components" mean?

Tags: graph-theory

What does "maximal number of closed cutting curves that do not disconnect the graph into multiple components" mean?

Particularly, what does closed cutting curves mean?

Comment: Where did you get this phrase?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork at 6.08: https://slideplayer.com/slide/4642205/

Answer (score 1):

The phrase refers to the topological *genus* of a surface... informally, the number of "holes" in the surface.

Consider a sphere (genus $0$).  Draw any closed cutting curve (a loop) on the surface of the sphere.  That "cut" will separate the points on the sphere *inside* the loop from those on the *outside* of the loop.  Such a curve "disconnects" the graph representing points on the sphere.  This is true no matter which closed loop you draw on the sphere.  Thus the "maximal" number having the property in the phrase is $0$... which is also the genus of a sphere.  (The same holds for any surface of genus $0$, such as a cube, an octohedron, a complicated sculpture without holes, ...)

Now consider a donut (genus $1$).  You *can* draw a closed loop encircling the "tube" of the donut and you will *not* "disconnect" the graph representing the points on the donut.  (Of course, if you drew a small closed loop on the surface, you could separate points on the donut, but the statement refers to the *maximal* number of such closed loops.) Once you cut the donut in this way, the resulting figure has genus $0$... and you cannot make another such closed loop cut and keep the figure connected.  Thus the *maximum* number of such loops you can create (keeping the figure connected) is $1$.

Now consider two donuts joined in the obvious way (genus $2$).  Now you can draw *two* separate closed loops and yet keep the surface (graph) connected.

And so forth.

Comment: But what about the size of the hole? Since one can draw only on the hole without causing disconnection, then is the hole size variable?

Comment: The size of the hole is irrelevant.  Think of cutting a donut, as I described.  The size of the hole is irrelevant.  (In fact, this is a problem in *topology*, in which deformations of the surface do not affect results.)

Comment: So it holds for all sizes and shapes of holes? As long as around it there's a connected portion of the original shape?

Comment: Yes... of course!  Why would the size of a hole in a donut matter at all whether you could cut around its tube to separate it?  Draw two different donuts and sketch for yourself.  Imagine one donut is the size you can dunk into your coffee, and the other donut is the size of the earth.  Why would such a size difference matter?!

Comment: Well because initially I was unsure e.g. whether the genus definition would allow other than circular holes, because that's all I saw in the examples. I also didn't see anywhere that one can make the surrounding area as small as possible. But that I inferred from the fact that it's only required that the surrounding area remain connected.